# Edit the REST API in Kubernetes source

Tags: kubernetes

I have modified kubectl's edit command (/pkg/kubectl/cmd/edit.go) to restart all active pods to reflect the new changes immediately after the edit is done. (A down time is acceptable in my use case). Now I want to include this feature to the REST api, where when I call

```
PATCH /api/v1/namespaces/{namespace}/replicationcontrollers/{name}
```

the patch should be applied to the replicationController and restart all the pods that are maintained by the corresponding replication controller. How ever I can't find the file that I should edit in order to alter the REST API. Where can I find these files and is there a better way to achieve what I am currently doing. (Edits to the RC should be reflect immediately in the pods)

Answer (score 0):

We're actually implementing this feature in the Deployment API. You want the Recreate update strategy. It will be in Kubernetes 1.2, but you can try it now, in v1.2.0-alpha.6 or by building from HEAD.

https://github.com/kubernetes/kubernetes/blob/master/docs/user-guide/deployments.md

That documentation is a little out of date, since Deployment is under active development. For the current API, please see
https://github.com/kubernetes/kubernetes/blob/master/pkg/apis/extensions/v1beta1/types.go